# API Installation Error on Mac

Tags: perl, bioperl

I'm having trouble installing the ensembl API. I've been using the installation guide on the [website](http://uswest.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/api_installation.html). First I had a hard time getting DBI and DBD mySQL modules, but once I used perlbrew I had no issues. However when running ping I get the error message:

```
ERROR: Error detected when connecting to Ensembl!
Looks like you need to setup your PERL5LIB with the Ensembl API. Please     consult http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/api_installation.html
================================================================================
If the problem persists please send the following error message to helpdesk@ensembl.org
Can't locate Bio/EnsEMBL/Registry.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Users/haleighmiller/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Users/haleighmiller/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4 /Users/haleighmiller/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.14.4/lib/5.14.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Users/haleighmiller/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.14.4/lib/5.14.4 .) at ./ping_ensembl.pl line 117.
```

I've followed the installation guide to the best of my knowledge, and couldn't find anything else online to help. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can't see your code but it seems pretty clear what the problem is. You need to set up your environment as described under point #3 on the page you linked to that explains the API installation. Strangely, there is no build/install process, so you have to manually extend the PERL5LIB variable to point to the correct place. You can run `echo $PERL5LIB` to see where the interpreter will search for modules.

The error message you posted shows that you need to add the correct Ensembl directories for the script to work. An easy test is to run `perl -MBio::EnsEMBL::Registry -e 1` at the command line. If it prints nothing, then everything is set correctly. If you see the same error message, that means the PERL5LIB variable is not set correctly.